# Simple thread conditional variable example giving deadlock in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, signals, deadlock

Hi I am toying around with threads and condition variables in ruby and I'm getting some very confusing results which don't make sense. I am following the [ConditionVariable example](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/ConditionVariable.html) from the ruby docs and everything seems to go as planned:

```
mutex = Mutex.new
resource = ConditionVariable.new

waiting_thread = Thread.new {
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts "Thread 'a' now needs the resource"
    resource.wait(mutex)
    puts "'a' can now have the resource"
    "a can now have the resource"
  }
}

signal_thread = Thread.new {
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts "Thread 'b' has finished using the resource"
    resource.signal
  }
}
```

This when running this code I get very expected output:

```
=> Thread 'a' now needs the resource
=> Thread 'b' has finished using the resource
=> 'a' can now have the resource
```

However the MOMENT I change it up a bit to `join` or get the `value` from the `waiting_thread`, it blows up with a `Deadlock` fatal error.

```
waiting_thread.value
signal_thread
```

Outputs:

> = Failure/Error: waiting_thread.value --
>          No live threads left. Deadlock?

I can vaguely understand what is happening -- both are trying to synchronize on the same mutex when the `waiting_thread` is indefinitely locked.

But in that case, why does the initial code work flawlessly giving the `put` statements in an expected asynchronous result?

This is somewhat important not only for my understanding but to toy around with concurrent testing. How can I use `join` and `value` with `ConditionVariables` to produce what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code from the Ruby docs can be a bit misleading, because it does not tell you that sending a signal does not buffer anywhere if the receiver is not waiting for it.

So the situation which will result in a deadlock will happen as follows:

1. `signal_thread` enters critical section and calls `resource.signal`. This signal will be lost.
2. `signal_thread` is done, and exits.
3. `waiting_thread` enters critical section and calls `resource.wait`. It's now locked waiting for a signal that never comes.
4. All threads are locked or inactive. No more live threads, therefore no one is able to wake up `waiting_thread` `-->` deadlock error.

You can get a deadlock error randomly on the sample code, depending on your CPU, OS, and the position of the sun or moon, if you just keep running it, because the order of the execution of `signal_thread` and `waiting_thread` is not deterministic. The order is random, therefore a deadlock may or may not happen, but it CAN happen depending on the execution order.

Now how do you solve it? Well, you need to guarantee `waiting_thread` waits, before `signal_thread` signals. We can do this using a `Queue`, like so:

```
mutex = Mutex.new
resource = ConditionVariable.new

sync_queue = Queue.new

waiting_thread = Thread.new {
  mutex.synchronize {
    puts "Waiting thread sending sync message..."
    sync_queue << 1

    puts "Thread 'a' now needs the resource"
    resource.wait(mutex)
    puts "'a' can now have the resource"
    "a can now have the resource"
  }
}

signal_thread = Thread.new {
  puts "Signal thread waiting for sync..."
  # signal_thread will sleep here, until there is something in the queue to pop.
  # This guarantees the right execution order. 
  sync_queue.pop

  mutex.synchronize {
    puts "Thread 'b' has finished using the resource"
    resource.signal
  }
}

waiting_thread.value
```

Now the code is deterministic, and `waiting_thread` will always wait before `signal_thread` signals, and the code will work as expected.

You just have to be aware that the `signal` call of a condition variable goes up in smoke if nobody is waiting on the other end. I think this important information is missing from the docs.

In addition to that the resource example is not really a very good example of checking if a resource is available in a critical section, because of this problem. If `signal_thread` already used the resource, then `waiting_thread` will never know it.

In a real situation there needs to be additional data shared between the threads, so that one thread can check if a resource is in use, and only THEN wait for a signal. If the resource is not already in use, then waiting for the signal is not needed, and in fact should not be done at all.

I.e. the ConditionVariable should not be used for checking resource state, only for signaling. In that case we are using condition variables more appropriately.

Comment: Casper, thank you so much for this detailed awesome response and solution! 

You are totally correct -- The signal_thread is firing first and the waiting_thread is just left to wait forever (causing the deadlock!). My only question with this new solution is why ever use `ConditionVariables` when `Thread::Queue`s do the same thing but better?

Comment: That's a very good question, but I think you get the answer once I tell you that `Queue` is basically implemented using condition variables (it's implemented in C-code, but it uses a condition variable-type implementation internally). Think of condition variables as the most basic thread control element, and then you can build more advanced implementations on top of that, like `Queue`. I think this article will give you some nice ideas: https://vaneyckt.io/posts/ruby_concurrency_in_praise_of_condition_variables/

Comment: Also note that `Queue` does not implement a timeout, which is available with `ConditionVariable`. However that does not mean you couldn't create your own `Queue` which would implement a timeout. But again you would most likely end up using condition variables internally for that.

Comment: Example of a `Queue` implementation with timeout: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/28/queue-pop-with-timeout-fixed/

Comment: These are great reads -- thanks a lot! (Going to share this information at a code review session !)